# Melt and Merge on Substring - Python & Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, melt

I have data which has data like

```
id      name    model_#   ms   bp1   cd1    sf1    sa1   rq1   bp2   cd2   sf2   sa2   rq2 ... 
1       John    23984     1    23    234    124     25   252   252    62   194    234   234 ... 
2       John    23984     2    234   234    242     62   262   622   262   622    26    262 ...
```

for hundreds of models with up to 10 ms and variables counting up to 21.

I have usually used pd.melt for doing my analysis where i look at bp1:bp21 or whatever. I currently have a need to create a melt where I look at bp1 values along with rq 1 values.

I am looking to effectively create something like this:

```
              id  model_#  ms  variable_x  value_x variable_y  value_y
0            113    77515   1        bp1     23        rq1      252
1            113    77515   1        bp2     252       rq2      262
2            113    77515   1        bp3     26        rq3      311
```

Right now the best I have been able to do is:

```
              id  model_#  ms variable_x  value_x variable_y  value_y
0            113    77515   1        bp1     23        rq1      252
1            113    77515   1        bp1     23        rq2      262
2            113    77515   1        bp1     23        rq3      311
3            113    77515   1        bp1     23        rq4      246
```

via:

```
df = pd.melt(dat, id_vars=['id', 'mod_req', 'ms'], value_vars=bp)
df1 = pd.melt(dat, id_vars=['id', 'mod_req', 'ms'], value_vars=rq)
df2 = pd.merge(df,df1, on=['id', 'mod_req', 'ms'])
```

Is there an easy way to merge on substring such that bp1 will connect with rq1 and so forth? This would mean taking a melted dataframe which only looks at bp1:bp21 and a other melted dataframe rq1:rq21 and merging based on the substring values( bp1 rq1, not bp1 rq2)

Comment: Your question here is pretty confusing, can you create a more simple case with inputs and expected outputs from that input?

Comment: You will forgive me, but this is about the simplest I can put it. I have lots of binned data bp1, bp2, bp3.... bp21 which i have converged into a variable with melt. I want to do the same thing with rq1, rq2, rq3... rq21, in such a way that each row contains bp1 rq1 value_x value_y. not bp1 rq2, thus i effectively want to merge the two melted dataframes(rq and bp) but along the substring (1 to 1, 2 to 2).

Comment: So, the cd1, sf1, and sa1 columns don't have any impact on your result?

Comment: Correct. It is just a slew of additional variables which must be considered when transforming the data from its original form.

Comment: Sorry if the differences in the random numbers i used caused confusion along that regard. There is no value changes, just row and column manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

Set the index...
Use a clever column `groupby`...
Another clever function to `apply`...

```
d1 = df.set_index(['id', 'name', 'model_#', 'ms'])

def melt_(df):
    id_vars = df.index.names
    return df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=id_vars).set_index(id_vars)


d2 = d1.groupby(d1.columns.str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False), axis=1).apply(melt_)

d2.columns = d2.columns.swaplevel(0, 1).map('_'.join)
d2.reset_index()

   id  name  model_#  ms variable_bp  value_bp variable_cd  value_cd variable_rq  value_rq variable_sa  value_sa variable_sf  value_sf
0   1  John    23984   1         bp1        23         cd1       234         rq1       252         sa1        25         sf1       124
1   2  John    23984   2         bp1       234         cd1       234         rq1       262         sa1        62         sf1       242
2   1  John    23984   1         bp2       252         cd2        62         rq2       234         sa2       234         sf2       194
3   2  John    23984   2         bp2       622         cd2       262         rq2       262         sa2        26         sf2       622
```

---

**Overly Functionalized**

```
e = lambda d, n: dict(zip(n, d.dtypes))
i = lambda d, n: pd.DataFrame(d.values, d.index, n).astype(e(d, n))
h = lambda d: i(d, d.columns.map(fmt)).reset_index()
m = lambda d: d.reset_index().melt(cols).set_index(cols)
fmt = '{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format

cols = ['id', 'name', 'model_#', 'ms']

d1 = df.set_index(cols)
g = d1.columns.str.extract('(\D+)', expand=False)
d1.groupby(g, axis=1).apply(m).pipe(h)

   id  name  model_#  ms variable_bp  value_bp variable_cd  value_cd variable_rq  value_rq variable_sa  value_sa variable_sf  value_sf
0   1  John    23984   1         bp1        23         cd1       234         rq1       252         sa1        25         sf1       124
1   2  John    23984   2         bp1       234         cd1       234         rq1       262         sa1        62         sf1       242
2   1  John    23984   1         bp2       252         cd2        62         rq2       234         sa2       234         sf2       194
3   2  John    23984   2         bp2       622         cd2       262         rq2       262         sa2        26         sf2       622
```

---

**Old Answer**

This is far from pretty and I'm not even sure this is what you want.

```
d1 = df.set_index(['id', 'name', 'model_#', 'ms'])

cidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    d1.columns.to_series().str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)', expand=False).values.tolist(),
    names=[None, 'variable']
)

d1.columns = cidx

d2 = d1.sort_index(axis=1).stack()

variables = pd.DataFrame(
    (d2.columns + d2.index.get_level_values('variable')[:, None]).tolist(),
    d2.index, d2.columns
)

d3 = pd.concat(
    [variables, d2], axis=1, keys=['variable', 'value']
).reset_index('variable', drop=True).sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)

d3.columns = d3.columns.map('_'.join)

d3.reset_index()

   id  name  model_#  ms variable_bp  value_bp variable_cd  value_cd variable_rq  value_rq variable_sa  value_sa variable_sf  value_sf
0   1  John    23984   1         bp1        23         cd1       234         rq1       252         sa1        25         sf1       124
1   1  John    23984   1         bp2       252         cd2        62         rq2       234         sa2       234         sf2       194
2   2  John    23984   2         bp1       234         cd1       234         rq1       262         sa1        62         sf1       242
3   2  John    23984   2         bp2       622         cd2       262         rq2       262         sa2        26         sf2       622
```

Comment: The output you have at the bottom is exactly what I am looking for (i was trying to shortcut a little by only keeping the two variables). Let me give this a try quickly. Tyvm for your help./

Comment: I'm working on something far more concise.  I should have it in a few minutes

Comment: @MaxU I mentally couldn't let this one go.  If I didn't get a satisfactory answer, it would have bothered me all day.  And I have a lot of work to do so I'm very fortunate I found a decent answer (-:

Comment: @piRSquared, yeah, this one looks much more elegant!

Comment: Thanks a piRSquared!

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using a list of regular expressions, taking advantage of the ordering (`bp1`, `rq1`, `bp2`, `rq2`, ...):

```py
# currently in dev
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(
    index = ['id', 'name', 'model_#'], 
    names_to = ('variable_x', 'variable_y'), 
    values_to = ['values_x', 'values_y'], 
    names_pattern = ['bp', 'rq'])

   id  name  model_# variable_x  values_x variable_y  values_y
0   1  John    23984        bp1        23        rq1       252
1   2  John    23984        bp1       234        rq1       262
2   1  John    23984        bp2       252        rq2       234
3   2  John    23984        bp2       622        rq2       262
```