# SQLite Query Performance, Transpose, Melt and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, merge, melt

**Background**

I'm working with Water Survey of Canada's [HyDat Database](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/cmc/hydrometrics/www/) of 8000+ hydrometric stations.  I've written code to query daily flow data:

```
conn = create_connection('db/Hydat.sqlite3')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DLY_FLOWS WHERE STATION_NUMBER=?", (station,))
```

After putting the returned data into a dataframe:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()    
column_headers = [description[0] for description in cur.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=column_headers)
```

The data is in approximately the following format:

```
STATION_NUM  YEAR  MONTH ...  FLOW1  FLAG1  FLOW2  FLAG2  ...  
02QC003      1965  02    ...  32.5   E      33.4   A      ...
02QC003      1965  03    ...  44.6   E      45.4   A      ...
02QC003      1965  04    ...  54.3   E      56.2   A      ... 
...          ...   ...   ...  ...    ...    ...    ...    ...
```

Where **N** in the FLOW**N** and FLAG**N** columns each go from 1 to 31 corresponding to the days of the month (requiring a filtering step later for days in months with < 31 days.

I'm trying to improve the performance of querying and reshaping the data into the following daily time-series format:

```
STATION_NUM  YEAR  MONTH  DAY  FLOW  FLAG
02QC003      1965  02     1    32.5  E
02QC003      1965  02     2    33.4  A
02QC003      1965  02     3    33.7  A
...          ...   ...    ...  ...   ...
```

The number of daily values I'm trying to transpose to rows gets as high as ~1000 (roughly equivalent to 100 years where one row represents a month, and daily values are in columns).  Not a problem dealing with a few queries, but I'm aiming for ~40M queries.  At the moment, I'm using the Pandas `melt` function, first for the daily flows, then for the data flags (not shown for brevity):

```
id_var_headers = column_headers[:11]

all_val_vars = [e for e in column_headers if 'FLOW' in e]
flow_val_vars = [e for e in all_val_vars if '_' not in e]

df_flows = pd.melt(df,
                   id_vars=id_var_headers,
                   value_vars=flow_val_vars,
                   value_name='DAILY_FLOW', 
                   var_name='DAY').sort_values(by=['YEAR', 'MONTH'])

df_flows['DAY'] = df_flows['DAY'].apply(
    map_day_to_var_name)

def map_day_to_var_name(s):
    if re.search('\d', s):
        return s[re.search('\d', s).span()[0]:]
```

I've found that the second slowest operation in the entire sequence is running in 10^-3 seconds, and the limiting step is the `melt` function, which appears to be in the order of 10x slower.  I'd like to achieve a 10x improvement on this step or better.

I tried using this as an opportunity to learn more about SQLite, and spent some time trying to figure out how I could structure a query to see if the 'transform' portion of my ETL process could be consolidated into one step and perform better than Pandas.  What I came up with works in theory (see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3cf0a/1)) but I'm struggling to implement it in my code. **See 2018-05-02 update for further detail.**

[This answer from user piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678202/melt-and-merge-on-substring-python-pandas) seems to be very close to what I'm after, although I'm stuck on the `groupby` function step. Following the steps outlined in piRSquared's answer, I was expecting the year and month to expand to unpivot the daily values, leading me to believe I'm incorrectly applying the `groupby` function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as well as any feedback on how I've presented my question (this is my first time posting a question).

**2018-04-20 Update with `wide_to_long`**

Scott Boston's suggestion is much tidier, although I needed to add a few steps:

First, I padded the days of the month < 10, otherwise the days are returned out of order.
`df.rename(columns={'FLOW1': 'FLOW01', ...}, inplace=True)`

Because I need a `DAY` column I also left out the `.drop('VARIABLE', axis=1)` to make the line:

`df = pd.wide_to_long(raw_df, ['FLOW', 'FLOW_SYMBOL'], idx_cols,
                      'DAY', sep='', suffix='.').reset_index()`

Testing on a record with 76K daily records, I get ~0.1s with the `melt` function, and ~0.6s with the `wide_to_long` function.

Is there another way I could improve this step?

**2018-05-02 UPDATE**

I went back and checked the response time for queries roughly representative of bounding lengths.  For a query of ~10 rows (short record), and one of > 1K rows (roughly the longest period of record in the database), I get a range of 0.04 to 0.1 s per query, respectively.  This result suggests to me that a better SQL query is not going to be better than a simple query followed by the pandas melt function.

**As a result, I think my current process is about as good as it's going to get.**

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `pd.wide_to_long`:

Given df:

```
  STATION_NUM  YEAR  MONTH  FLOW1 FLAG1  FLOW2 FLAG2
0     02QC003  1965      2   32.5     E   33.4     A
1     02QC003  1965      3   44.6     E   45.4     A
2     02QC003  1965      4   54.3     E   56.2     A
```

Use `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,['FLOW','FLAG'],['STATION_NUM','YEAR','MONTH'],'VARIABLE',sep='',suffix='.')\
  .reset_index().drop('VARIABLE', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  STATION_NUM  YEAR  MONTH  FLOW FLAG
0     02QC003  1965      2  32.5    E
1     02QC003  1965      2  33.4    A
2     02QC003  1965      3  44.6    E
3     02QC003  1965      3  45.4    A
4     02QC003  1965      4  54.3    E
5     02QC003  1965      4  56.2    A
```

Comment: Thanks Scott.  your solution with wide_to_long is much tidier, but it seems to have the same order of performance (~10^-1 seconds) per call.  I'll update my question with this information.  If there's no faster way with a pandas function, is there a way to improve the data transform using another method, i.e. with a better SQLite query?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing 31 `SELECT`s, one for each day's columns, then `UNION`'ing all the days together?  It will certainly be a large amount of repetitive SQL, and I don't know enough to predict whether it will be any faster than Pandas.

Comment: Thanks for your response Alex.  I went back and tested the performance of simple queries, (neglecting the complexity to deal with 2x31 joins in series), and it seems like it isn't any faster than my Pandas approach.  I've updated my question with this information.